# (X×Y)∖(A×B)= ((X\A)×Y)∪(X×(Y\B))?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am solving the following equation out of a book:

(X×Y)∖(A×B)= ((X\A)×Y)∪(X×(Y\B))

However i have strong doubts that this is a typo since i am getting a different result everytime. Can someone check my logical connections and see if im right or if i am wrong?

Let (x,y)∈ ((X×Y)∖(A×B))

Definition of \ applied

⇔(x,y) ∈ (X×Y) ^ (x,y)∉ (A×B)

defintion of × applied

⇔ (x∈X ^ yεY) ^(x∉A ^ y∉B)

(Now i will demand  (x∈X ^ yεY)  twice)

⇔  (x∈X ^ yεY) ^  (x∈X ^ yεY)  ^ (x∉A ^ y∉B)

(Commutation and assosication applied)

⇔ x∈X ^ x∉A ^ y∈Y ^ x∈X ^ y∈Y ^ y∉B

Definition of \ and defintion of × applied

⇔ (x,y)∈ ((X\A)×Y) ^ (x,y)∈ (X×(Y\B))

defintion of × applied

⇔(x,y)∈ (X\A)×Y) ∩ (X×(Y\B))

Thus follows  ((X×Y)∖(A×B))=(X\A)×Y) ∩ (X×(Y\B))

I tried to get the other direction to equal the first in order to check if they wrongly typed  ∪ instead of ∩ however i gave up since it got really compliated.

Comment: You can picture what's going on by imagining a rectangle with X being (the set of points in) the base, Y the vertical side, A the left portion of X and B the bottom portion of Y. Then the left side of the equation is (the big rectangle minus the lower left quarter), and the right side is union of the right half and the top half, giving the same three quarters of the rectangle for both formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x,y) \notin A \times B$ does not mean $x \notin A$ AND $y \notin B$. It means $x \notin A$ OR $y \notin B$.

Comment: Thanks dear sir! I completely missed that! My appreciation !